# Characterization of separable polynomials over any commutative unitary ring.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and $f(T) \in R[T]$ a monic polynomial over $R$. Then $f(T)$ is *separable* if $(f(T), \frac{d}{dt}f(T))=(1)=R[T]$ where $\frac{d}{dt}f(T)$ is the formal derivative of $f(T)$.

The example 3.4 from the Milne's book "Étale Cohomology" says:

> $f$ is separable if and only if its image in $k(\mathfrak{p})[T]$ is separable for all prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}$ in $R$.

The "if" part is clear. Since there exist $\alpha , \beta \in R[T]$ such that $\alpha f +\beta \frac{d}{dt}f=1$ and its image equall to $1$ in $k(\mathfrak{p})[T]$, the images of $f$ and $\frac{d}{dt}f$ generates $k(\mathfrak{p})[T]$.

I do not understand the "only if" part.

Comment: Suppose $(f,g)\subset P$, where $P$ is a prime of $R[T]$. Let $p=P\cap R$. Note that $pR[T]\subset P$. The extension of $P$ to $R_p[T]$ (let's denote it by $Q$) has the following properties: $pR_p=Q\cap R_p$, and $pR_p[T]\subset Q$. Obviously, $(\bar f,\bar g)\subset Q/pR_p[T]$ which is a prime ideal of $R_p[T]/pR_p[T]=(R_p/pR_p)[T]=k(p)[T]$.

Comment: @user268547 Your comment holds for any ideal $I$ of $R[T]$. So The equality $I = R[T]$ can be determined from that the equality $\bar{I} = k(\mathfrak{p})[T]$ holds for any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of R. It is very useful! Thank you very much!